# What ways are there to enter a foe's space without triggering an Attack of Opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, size-scaling

A friend is suggesting a very odd Christmas one-shot, where everyone plays as kids, talking animals, snowmen, etc...but also as 20th level Gestalt characters, allowing just about any Pathfinder or 3.5 3rd party materials.

I'm inclined to play as a gingerbread man, and my friend found [this race](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Jiinja_(3.5e_Creature))...and now I'm thoroughly amused by the thought of building a 6" tall martial character.

One key question:

**What are ways to profitably enter a foe's space without triggering an Attack of Opportunity?**

3rd party suggestions (e.g. Spheres of Might? Path of War?) are great, as are 3.5 materials. Feat intensive options are fine too. (I'll have oodles of feats to play with.)

Options that give advantages to diminutive characters entering larger creatures' spaces (e.g. a [Mouser Swashbuckler](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler/archetypes/paizo-swashbuckler-archetypes/mouser)'s "Underfoot Assault"...but that only lets one enter a larger creature's space when that creature missed them with an attack.

Comment: Small correction, the Mouser Swashbuckler's 'Underfoot Assault' can be used when an enemy misses with a melee attack, not an AoO.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I've fixed it for clarity in the Q.

Comment: Be aware that the homebrew race's natural ability **irresistible** should immediately obviate  a great many combat encounters, making any fightin' ability the PC possesses pale in comparison to the PC's ability to manipulate others with his skills and special abilities… unless, of course, the GM plans to rule that "circumstances dictate" the ability ceases to function *all the time!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Underfoot Combat feat does what you want.

Underfoot Combat (*Races of the Wild*, p. 152) provides the following benefit:

> You can move into or through a square occupied by a creature at least two size categories larger than you. You do not provoke attacks of opportunity for doing so.

Since you're playing a diminutive creature, that means any creature that's small or larger, which covers the vast majority of opponents.

This feat is also a prerequisite for the Confound the Big Folk feat (RotW, p. 153), which provides various maneuvers you can pull off to gain combat advantages by entering a larger opponent's space, the best of which is treating them as flat-footed (enabling easy sneak attacks).

These feats were combined to great effect in a build known as "the other, melee killer gnome" (h/t KRyan) - you might be interested in mining the [build thread](https://web.archive.org/web/20130129010622/http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19872846/I_May_Be_Tiny_But_Youre_Dead_the_other_melee_Killer_Gnome_for_your_pleasure) (archive link) for ideas.

Comment: There’s a build known as “the _other_ killer gnome” that might be worth looking up and nothing at the end there—if I remember correctly, it focuses a lot on Confound the Big Folk.